# target iframe when iframe name is dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

My problem is targeting an iframe with a dynamic name added from jquery. It seems when I attempt to add name to iframe dynamically, links targeting the iframe, open in a new window.

The test code is simple:

html:

```
<a href="https://www.gaugeonline.com/" target="iframe1">test</a>
<iframe src="https://test.com"></iframe>
```

jquery:

```
$('iframe').attr('name', 'iframe1');
```

I made a simple fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2ztg7xpj/1/

I also tried adding both the target and name dynamically:

html:

```
<a href="https://www.gaugeonline.com/">test</a>
<iframe src="https://test.com"></iframe>
```

jquery:

```
$('iframe').attr('name', 'iframe1');
$('a').attr('target', 'iframe1');
```

and the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2ztg7xpj/2/

So the question is, why is this the behavior for a dynamically added iframe name and is there some sort of work around (other than adding name directly to the iframe)

Answer (score 1):

I still am baffled by the default behavior. Seems like a new way to avoid popup blockers.

In any event I created my own workaround fix.

```
$('a[target=frame1]').click( function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href= $(this).attr('href');
    $('iframe[name=frame1]').attr('src', href);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I live with this by after setting the iframe name next calling DOM function [replaceWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith) to replace the iframe with itself.  Then it works.

In plain JavaScript something like

```
{
    const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    iframe.name = 'iframe1';
    iframe.replaceWith(iframe);
}
```